# How to make this kotlin script do checks with errors, but return a value in an idiomatic way?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I wrote this function here to fetch an API key required during our gradle build:

```
fun getApiKey(): String {
    val keyFile = File("../whatever")
    if (!keyFile.exists()) {
        logger.error("whatever missing from parent directory")
    }

    val regex = "ARTIFACTORY_APIKEY: (\\S+)".toRegex()
    var key:String?  = null
    keyFile.forEachLine {
        val matchResult = regex.find(it)
        if (matchResult != null) {
            key = matchResult.groupValues[1]
        }
    }

    if (key == null) {
        logger.error("whatever doesn't contain API KEY")
    }

    return key!!
}
```

It gets the job done (gives meaningful error messages when my file is missing or has bad content), and returns the value otherwise. But well, it feels overly clumsy, I am sure there must be more elegant ways to express such functionality within a gradle file?

Comment: This seems like a Code Review question. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tenfour04 I know, but I consider the above so bad code that I can't consider it a working solution ...

Answer (score 1):

I'll split the code in two functions like this:

```
    fun getApiKey(): String =
        File("../whatever").apply { keyFile ->
            if (!keyFile.exists()) {
                logger.error("whatever missing from parent directory")
            }

            findKey(keyFile) ?: run {
                logger.error("whatever doesn't contain API KEY")
                ""
            }
        }
    
    fun findKeyInFile(keyFile: File): String?
    {
        val regex = "ARTIFACTORY_APIKEY: (\\S+)".toRegex()
        keyFile.forEachLine {
            regex.find(it)?.let { matchResult ->
                return@forEachLine matchResult.groupValues[1]
            }
        }
        
        return null
    }
```

I think that your code has a potential error when you force the cast of the returning `key` string (`return key!!`).

In fact, if the value is `null` then it would throw a `NullPointerException`.
In my code, I return an empty string if the `findKeyInFile` function returns null.

Comment: First, addendum: in the end, I figured that I do not want to call `logger.error` but to simply throw a GradleException.

Comment: But then, the **return** gives me an error: **return is not allowed here**. I tried to use `return@methodname` that doesnt change it. Strange.

Comment: The reason for that error message is that `forEachLine()` isn't an inlined function, thus a return from its lambda isnt valid. Thus: the above source is wrong on that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a lot of room for improvement. You can use `File.useLines` to get a Sequence of lines so you don't process more than necessary. It will only read one line at a time, so if you use `firstOrNull()` on the sequence, it won't read past the first line that satisfies your predicate.

And you could benefit from throwing exceptions instead of merely logging errors, because it avoids the need to use `!!`.

```
fun getApiKey(): String {
    val keyFile = File("../whatever")
    if (!keyFile.exists()) {
        throw GradleException("whatever missing from parent directory")
    }

    val regex = "ARTIFACTORY_APIKEY: (\\S+)".toRegex()

    return keyFile.useLines { lines ->
        lines.mapNotNull { regex.find(it) }
            .firstOrNull()
            ?: throw GradleException("whatever doesn't contain API KEY")
    }.groupValues[1]
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that part about logging was stupid on my side. I thought that would throw right there.